Вычисление интервала в зависимости от продолжительности видео
Продолжительность любая: 5/500/1000/10000 секунд. Нужно рассчитать интервал, через который необходимо доставать кадр из видео. Придумал такой вариант: продолжительность делим на 100. Если интервал более 10 секунд, фиксируем на 10 секундах:
inerval = time / 100
inerval = inerval if inerval < 10 else 10

Возможно, есть более универсальный вариант? И возможно ли данное уcловие писать не в 2, а в 1 строчку?

min(time / 100, 10)

А может быть лучше max(1, min(time / 100, 10)) ибо какой смысл доставать по сути каждый кадр на коротких видео

То что необходимо, спс
